# Application Run Failed in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning SpringBoot through a tutorial, building a sample website with an API for a company's employee database. When I try to run the application, I get the following message:

```java
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadDatabase' defined in file [/Users/westonjorgensen/Downloads/payroll/target/classes/com/company/payroll/LoadDatabase.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.company.payroll.LoadDatabase$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6abc07cf]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The declared package "payroll" does not match the expected package "com.company.payroll"
The method save(Employee) is undefined for the type EmployeeRepository
The method save(Employee) is undefined for the type EmployeeRepository
```

The entire project is here https://github.com/wjorgensen/payroll.git

The tutorial I am following is https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Any ideas on how to solve the issue?

Comment: The "nested exception" is the root cause, so the first thing that went wrong - and caused all the subsequent failures - is the last part of the error message, i.e. the two "unresolved compilation problems". If you google those two messages (about the "expected package" and "the method save ... is undefined", you should find an explanation of what they mean and how they can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package problem.

The exception mentions `<...>/com/company/payroll/LoadDatabase.class` but your project does not contain `LoadDatabase.java` class in `src/main/java/com/company/payroll`. Try moving all your classes from `com.company.payroll` package to `payroll` package as described in the tutorial you are following.